# Precalculus math problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus

There were 238 tickets purchased for a major league baseball game. The general admission tickets cost 6.50 dollars and the upper reserved tickets cost 8.00 dollars. The total amount of money spent was 1800.50 dollars. How many of each kind of ticket were purchased?

Comment: You could say that an odd number of general admission tickets were bought (can you see why?)

Answer (score 1):

Let $x$ be the number of general admission tickets. Let $y$ be the total number of upper-reserved tickets. Then, $y=238-x$. So,
$$6.5x+8y=1800.5\\
6.5x+8(238-x)=1800.5\\
6.5x+1904-8x=1800.5\\
-1.5x=1800.5-1904$$
You should be able to solve this now.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  Let there be $n$ general admission tickets sold.  Then how many upper reserved tickets were sold?  What was the total revenue from each type?  Add them together and use the number you are given to evaluate $n$.

Answer (score 0):

I have to say, that's pretty cool how the dollar sign affected your text.

For the question: start off with what you know - \$6.50 for general, \$8.00 for upper reserved. And we know that the total amount of money spent was \$1800.50, and that 238 tickets were sold.

Take $x$ to be the number of general tickets sold, and $y$ to be the number of upper tickets sold. We therefore can derive the equation:

$x+y=238$

Because we know that the total number of tickets sold is equal to 238.

Next let's use the money we were given. We know the total amount of money was \$1800.50. Well, we know that people spent \$6.50 on each of the $x$ general tickets and \$8.00 on the upper reserved ones, so we can draw the equation:

$6.5x+8y=1800.5$

Now you've got a systems of equation. Let's solve for x, because it seems easiest. Take the first equation and multiply both sides by 8:

$8x+8y=1904$

Subtract that from the second equation and you get:

$1.5x=103.5$

$x=69$

**69 generals sold**, and by subtracting from the total of 238, we know that **169 reserved sold**.

Comment: This is a homework problem. You are not supposed to reveal the answer.

Comment: @SanathDevalapurkar That's a rule?

Comment: I believe so - when I posted the answer (on a different question), I was also asked not to reveal the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If all tickets would have been sold for 8 bucks the income would have been 1904, so we are 203.50 dollars off.  Now $203.50:1.5=69$.